# Rotational quantum states for atoms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, spectroscopy

It is well-established that molecules possess rotational and vibrational quantum states, due to molecular symmetries, in addition to electronic states. In contrast, it is generally accepted that atoms have **only** electronic states. The absence of vibrational states is understandable. However, the rationale behind the absence of rotational states in atoms, mainly due to the spherical symmetry of atoms, is less clear. If an atom is in the **S orbital**, it is indeed spherically symmetric in all respects and should not have any rotational state. But when an atom is in an asymmetric electronic orbital, such as the **P orbital**, it loses its symmetry as the shape of the orbital is angle-dependent. The question then arises: why doesn't such an atom possess any (discrete) rotational states? If such an atom starts spinning, then how the extra energy is shown on the electronic energy diagram of the atom? Why in atomic gases we always exclude the rotational degrees of freedom in determining the total energy of the system or even its temperature?

Comment: An asymetric orbital cannot rotate, the orbital itself is the the average shape of a rotating (orbiting) electron. Imagine a classical eliptical orbit of a planet about the sun. The orbit itself is the rotational mode. You cannot rotate the orbit as it it were an object to get a different orbit which would become a rotating ellipse, such an orbit does not exist, only a fixed ellipse can exist.

Comment: For something to be able to rotate, you should imagine it has at least two parts that can remain either in a fixed position or that it can start to rotate, but when the object is the orbit itself, this no longer makes sense.

Comment: The states with non-zero angular momentum (p,d,f,etc) *are* the rotational states

Answer (score 1):

I do not think what your talking about has anything to do with spherical symmetry as an extended sphere is very much capable of rotating. Concerning rotations of the Atom I would say there are 3 different things I could imagine being meant by it:

First as mentioned in the comments we have exited electronic states in which the electron is carrying angular momentum. Those could be imagined as states of the electron rotating around the core and are already fully included in what you call “electronic states“ in your Question. Also note that the probability density in these states is always symmetrical around the angular momentum axis. Now I could imagine that the description of rotational states might get way more complicated if you would want to fully include the motion of the core during the electron rotation for a many electron Atom, but for practical purposes assuming the core to be stable seems to be good enough unless you want to describe positronium or some kind of exziton, which then are mostly 2 body problems though.

Then we have the spin states of the electron and nucleus which, while talking about rotation might be incorrect here, do indeed carry angular momentum.

Lastly I would assume one could image the Nucleus itself rotating. While my knowledge on quantum chromodynamics is very limited I would assume that this is indeed possible, however due to the low moment of inertia of the Nucleus the first excited state would already need insanely high energy to occur and therefore be irrelevant for any practical purposes on commonly used energy scales.

I currently can’t think of anything else you could imagine as a rotating state of an atom.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Essentially, we neglect the rotational degrees of freedom around the atom's center-of-mass (CM) because of the atom's small spatial extent (radius ~ Angstrom), leading to a negligible moment of inertia, not because of its spherical symmetry. Right? Isn’t against the conventional wisdom that the smaller the moment of inertia, the easier to rotate?

Comment: What you said is true for the rotational degrees of the nucleus (radius ~ $10^{-15} m$). Considering the electronic component of the Atom  (radius ~ Angstrom $= 10^{-10} m$): Their rotation is fully included in the electronic states of the atom used in the Quantum mechanical description, they are not neglected.

Comment: Yes I do agree neglecting rotation due to low moment of inertia is somewhat unintuitive, but the increase of the energy needed to excite the first rotational state increasing with lowered moment of inertia is indeed the correct quantum mechanical behavior. 

$$E_\ell = B\; \ell \left (\ell+1\right)\quad
\textrm{with}\quad B \equiv \frac{\hbar^2}{2I}$$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_rotor)

Comment: I just checked out the Wikipedia link you referenced. It was helpful. Thanks @Zaph!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood your point and I think it makes sense.